# cx_Oracle Giving DLL load failed exception

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I have

- **Oracle 11g client** installed,
- 64 bit Windows 7 machine,
- Python 3.4,
- cx_Oracle 64 bit installed.

Still facing the exception `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.` during run time.

Comment: Anyone have any idea on this? I have referred previous posts too. But did not get my problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the Oracle client, the Python installation and the cx_Oracle installation all match with each other. In your case you need to make sure they are all 64-bit and also all 11g. Second, if all of that is correct and you are still getting that error, you'll need to find out what dependency is missing. You can use this tool for that purpose:

http://www.dependencywalker.com/